# Developing a function to show time without imports

Tags: python, time

```
def show_time(hour,min):
    hour = int(input())
    min = ''
    for hour in (hour,min):
        while 24 >= hour > 12:
            hour -= 12
            min == min
            return hour, ":" min,'pm'
        if hour < 12:
            if 0 <= min <= 59 
            hour == hour
            min == min
            return hour, ":" min,'am'
```

So this is my code so far.^^
When I run this code, i keep getting an infinite loop for one... another thing is.. I feel like i am totally off.   Btw.. I am trying to do this without importing anything and using the string formatting method.  Please HELP!
Here were my instructions...

def show_time(hour,min): Accept integers    for the hour    (values from    0   to  23) and the minute
(values from    0   to  59). Construct  the correct clock   representation, such    as  the examples    below.
o you   must    use the format  method.
o Examples:

```
! show_time(9,15) → "9:15am"
! show_time(0,0) → "12:00am"
! show_time(12,0) → "12:00pm"
! show_time(22,5) → "10:05pm"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get what you're trying to achieve using loops, but here's a simple solution.

```
def show_time(hour, minutes):
    if hour >= 12:
        suffix = "pm"
        if hour != 12:
            hour -= 12
    else:
        suffix = "am"
        if hour == 0:
            hour = 12
    return "{0}:{1:02}{2}".format(hour, minutes, suffix)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Correct code should be like this:

```
def show_time(hour,min):
    hour = int(hour)
    min = int(min)
    if hour > 12:
        hour -= 12
        return str(hour) + ":" + str(min) + 'pm'
    else:
        return str(hour) + ":" + str(min) + 'am'

print show_time(9,15)
```

You should think on simple level. For and while loops are unnecessary.

Comment: Oh i'm not allowed to call print either... Would replacing print with return do the same thing?  And i just think too much into it i guess.

Comment: @Bonjovi14 You can use `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()` but requires `import sys`. So there is no any solution to print a value without using print :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def show_time(hour, min):
    if hour > 24 or min > 59 or hour < 0 or min < 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input")
    # which half of day is this?
    is_pm = (hour / 12.0) > 1
    # normalize time in 0 to 11
    hour = hour % 12
    # get the correct half of day readable form
    half_day = "pm" if is_pm else "am"
    # print it out
    print "%02d:%02d%s" % (hour, min, half_day)
```

Always try too keep things simple when possible, loops are useful but try to question whether they are really necessary.